# Are the assets instantly transferred in this smart contract?

Tags: solidity, nft, solidity-0.8.x, auctions

I am entirely new to solidity and web3 in general so I am not entirely sure how to frame this question but are the NFTs instantly transferred once a user bids in this dutch auction smart contract?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/utils/Counters.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    uint256 public immutable startPrice = 5 ether;
    uint256 public immutable startAt;
    uint256 public immutable endsAt;
    uint256 public immutable endPrice = 2 ether;
    uint256 public immutable discountRate = 0.01 ether;
    uint256 public duration = 300 hours;
    uint256 public immutable MAX_SUPPLY = 10000;

    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {
        startAt = block.timestamp;
        endsAt = block.timestamp + duration;
    }

    function price() public view returns (uint256) {
        if (endsAt < block.timestamp) {
            return endPrice;
        }

        uint256 minutesElapsed = (block.timestamp - startAt) / 3600;

        return startPrice - (minutesElapsed * discountRate);
    }

function safeMint(address to) public payable {
    require(msg.value >= price(), "Not enough ether sent");
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    require(tokenId < MAX_SUPPLY, "No more items left.");
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    _safeMint(to, tokenId + 1);
}

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

If not, how can I instantly transfer it?

Answer (score 0):

It should appear immediately in the sender wallet if `safeMint` is completed successfully (1).

```
function safeMint(uint256 amount) public payable {
    require(msg.value >= (amount * price()), "Not enough ether sent");
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    require(tokenId < MAX_SUPPLY, "No more items left.");
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId + 1);
}
```

The code has one issue `amount` is only used to check the price, it is never used to mint tokens.

Note (1): Ethereum is a proof of work blockchain so transactions aren't final immediately. It could happen that a chain reorg changes the tokenId assigned if someone else is minting tokens at the same block height.

Comment: Hey I have edited the code. Can you check if its okay now?

Comment: @Mehsilsem I can't test the code but it seems to be fine. Just a minor nitpick is that `minutesElapsed` isn't in minutes but hours.